# Make firebase user information view able only by the user and admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying set up Firebase security rules for Cloud Firestore that only i can write. But Everyone can be read it.

Here is my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure set up the security rules for it. How do i set up or test with simulator that user information view able only by the user and admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to test your rules.  You can use the [rules simulator in the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator).  Go to the rules tab to find it.

You can also test rules locally using the [Firestore rules emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator), using code to check if the rules do what you expect.